# How to do multiple gpu programming in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I am using following code to do parallelization, however, I am not able to do that. It throws some random errors. I am using amazon aws for training. So when I run this training putty stops responding.
codes :

```
for d in ['/device:GPU:0','/device:GPU:1','/device:GPU:2', '/device:GPU:3', '/device:GPU:4','/device:GPU:5','/device:GPU:6','/device:GPU:7']:
    with tf.device(d):
        pred1 = cae(x, weights1, biases1, keepprob)
        cost1 = calculateL2loss(pred1, tf.reshape(y, shape=[-1,dimension,dimension,1]))
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
sess.run(init)
sess.run(optm1, feed_dict = {x:batch_xs_noisy, y:batch_xs, keepprob:1})
```

Please suggest me, how to do parallel programming in such cases.

Comment: Are you sure you have 8 GPUs?

Comment: Also, what is your error?

Comment: Yes i am using 8 gpu p2.8xlarge. the problem is that it doesn't give any error, it simply crashes the putty.